# Lowercase/Uppercase String Comparision Issue

Tags: javascript, string, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

If I use the function "WithText" in the Testcafe script, it looks like it depends on lowercase and uppercase writing. How I can make it independent? SO a user "Myname" is accepted and also "myname"? It is bad that a script will fail in case of translation issues.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common issue with strings in most programming languages:

- Convert the input string to either upper/lower case
- Perform the same action with your comparison string
- Compare the modified string Objects